# Adjust spacing between personal information & photo columns in moderncv classic

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, moderncv, horizontal

I wish to reduce the spacing between the personal information column and the photo column in `moderncv` classic style.

Here is a `MWE`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\address{83 Fancy Avenue}{Noweheresville}{Gotham City 24061} 
\phone[mobile]{123 456 7890}
\email{someone@xyz.com}
\photo[64pt][0.5pt]{example-image-a}

\begin{document}
   \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: moderncv header with photo spacing marked up]

How can I control/reduce/fine-tune the horizontal space indicated in the above PDF output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the value of `\separatorcolumnwidth` to the value you need.

See for example the code (see marked code with `<`=======`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\address{83 Fancy Avenue}{Noweheresville}{Gotham City 24061} 
\phone[mobile]{123 456 7890}
\email{someone@xyz.com}
\photo[64pt][0.5pt]{example-image-a}

\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0mm} % <==============================

\begin{document}
   \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

To get the usual distance back after the title just use `\setlength` again:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\address{83 Fancy Avenue}{Noweheresville}{Gotham City 24061} 
\phone[mobile]{123 456 7890}
\email{someone@xyz.com}
\photo[64pt][0.5pt]{example-image-a}

\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0mm} % <==============================

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{9pt}% <===============================
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer.  How do we know the default value for this parameter?

Comment: thank u. But your solution has a side effect of messing up the spacing between the `cventry` column and the main column, and is therefore __not__ viable

Comment: great. Thank you so much. Accepted and upvoted.